# How can the rank change when changing $n$ rows of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I know that when changing one row of a matrix, the rank can either increase by one, decrease by one, or stay the same.

So is it true that when changing $n$ rows, the rank can either increase by $n$, decrease by $n$, or stay the same?

Comment: Try to make examples yourself!

Comment: What sort of changes are allowed?  In general, the rank can increase by $n$, decrease by $n$, **increase or decrease by an amount smaller than n** or stay the same.  By changing $n$ rows, you could of course change the rank by $n-2$, *it doesn't have to explicitly be* $n$ like your question seems to imply and the rank of course cannot exceed the number of rows or columns of the matrix itself and cannot be negative.  For examples of the extremes, consider starting with the zero matrix and changing the rows to get the identity or vice versa.

Comment: @JeanMarie: No problem. I will delete my comments and clarify the sentence. Unfortunately I am a monoglot and linguistic sensitivity not a strength!

Comment: Changing $n$ rows is the same as changing one row $n$ times, so the answer depends on what happens at each step. Any change from $-n$ to $+n$ is possible.

Comment: I delete my comments too. Have a good day (for me, in France, it's evening)